# PHP deleting images editing location

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
function deleteImage($image){
    //$image is a varchar like 2016/10/example.jpg from MySQL
    $myArray = explode('/', $image);

    $result = $s3->deleteObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => 'uploads/avatars/'.$myArray[0].'/'.$myArray[1].'/xs-'.$myArray[2]
    ));
}
```

Basically for `$image = 2016/10/example.jpg`

I need to delete the image located in

```
uploads/avatars/2016/10/xs-example.jpg
```

I tried to figure it out the problem for hours but it's not working and seems impossible to debug.

Comment: Does it work if you just hard-code the path you want, ie `'Key' => 'uploads/avatars/2016/10/xs-example.jpg'`?

Comment: @Phil Yes I did and it works

Comment: can you do a var_dump($image); and paste result here ?

Comment: @sadok-f I already tried, but it returns me always nothing

Comment: so the variable is empty ? can you paste the code where you call it from ?

Comment: @sadok-f I call it like `deleteImage(array($verify['image']));` ...but if I try `'Key'    => 'uploads/avatars/'.$image` it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for something like this

```
$key = sprintf('uploads/avatars/%s/xs-%s',
        ltrim(dirname($image), '/'), basename($image));
```

The `ltrim` is probably overkill but it's just in case your `$image` variable starts with a `/`.

This should handle any path depth you throw at it.

See

- [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/function.dirname.php)
- [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/function.basename.php)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your function with an Array as argument, instead of `deleteImage(array($verify['image']));` you should call it `deleteImage($verify['image']);`

Comment: Thanks, but also with `foreach($image as $name) { $result = $s3->deleteObject(array( ...etc`